# How to stop Visual Studio 2019 keeping my console application after the Main method has terminated?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am doing C# Hello world on visual studio and my console is holding without the Readkey, how could I stop it?

Answer (score 3):

It's a feature of the debugger. Your application is still exiting as you expect:

[image]

As you can see, the debug console stays open and records the exit code of the console application after it exited. It even tells you how to change this behaviour:

> To automatically close the console when debugging stops, enable Tools->Options->Debugging->Automatically close the console when debugging stops.

Comment: Kinda hilarious as the answer was right there in his terminal lol